# Burndown query data via api does not match Report in VersionOne

Tags: versionone

I'm using the below query to provide me burndown data to be used by a chart -

```
from: Timebox
select:
  - Name
  - Workitems.ToDo.@Sum
where:
  BeginDate: 2014-01-30T00:00:00.000000
  Schedule.ScheduledScopes.Name: My Project Name
asof: 2014-01-30
---
from: Timebox
select:
  - Name
  - Workitems.ToDo.@Sum
where:
  BeginDate: 2014-01-30T00:00:00.000000
  Schedule.ScheduledScopes.Name: My Project Name
asof: 2014-01-31
---
....
```

And the big query is formed by attaching the individual queries with the asof date incrementing until the present date.

The data from this query is way off from the report shown in Version One.  So what am I doing wrong?

I want the data from this query in this format so it can be charted by d3js -

```
[{'date': '30-Jan-14', 'todo': 980},
 {'date': '31-Jan-14', 'todo': 2632},
 {'date': '03-Feb-14', 'todo': 3778},
 {'date': '04-Feb-14', 'todo': 3716},
 {'date': '05-Feb-14', 'todo': 3620},
 {'date': '06-Feb-14', 'todo': 3354},
 {'date': '07-Feb-14', 'todo': 2965},
 {'date': '10-Feb-14', 'todo': 2752},
 {'date': '11-Feb-14', 'todo': 2266}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous query was returning Workitems from all Projects, don't know how to restrict it to a project.

Anyway, I've gone ahead with this query, rooted on Scope (project).  The only problem is that it takes solid 20secs to run.  Any pointers on how to make it run faster?  Also, I've to manually rollup the ToDo sum for a given day.

```
from: Scope
select:
    - from: Workitems:PrimaryWorkitem
      select:
        - Children.ToDo.@Sum
      where:
          Timebox.Name: My Sprint Name
where:
    Name: My Project Name
asof: 2014-01-30
---
from: Scope
select:
    - from: Workitems:PrimaryWorkitem
      select:
        - Children.ToDo.@Sum
      where:
          Timebox.Name: My Sprint Name
where:
    Name: My Project Name
asof: 2014-01-31
---
.....
```